# PIG Algebraic UDF with arguments : Combiner optimizer error

Tags: optimization, apache-pig

I'm trying to build a Pig UDF that performs some aggregation on a variable of type double.  To do so, I built an algebraic UDF called **Aggreg**.  It is called in the following script:

```
REGISTER 'Test.jar';
DEFINE Aggreg com.pig.test.Agreg();
records = LOAD '/tmp/Test.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (v1:chararray, v2:double);
grouped_rec = GROUP records ALL;
test = FOREACH grouped_rec GENERATE Aggreg(records.v2) AS val;
DUMP test;
```

This works fine as it is.  Then, I wanted to use the arguments for this UDF so I added a public constructor with one `String` argument.

I just changed the `DEFINE` statement in the previous script but haven't yet used the argument in the UDF Java code:

```
DEFINE Aggreg com.pig.test.Agreg('Test');
```

And now I get the following error:

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2018: Internal error. Unable to introduce the combiner for optimization.

Any ideas where this could come from?

Answer (score 0):

Using Algebraic interface, you must implement two constructors in classes Initial, Intermed and Final, the default constructor and constructor with the parameter you use.

```
static public class Initial extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {
    public Initial(){}
    public Initial(String str){Aggreg.string=trs;}

    @Override
    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
}

static public class Intermed extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {
    public Intermed(){}
    public Intermed(String str){Aggreg.string=trs;}

    @Override
    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        ...
    }

}

static public class Final extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {
    public Final(){}
    public Final(String str){Aggreg.string=trs;}

    @Override
    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
}

public String getInitial() {
    return Initial.class.getName();
}

public String getIntermed() {
    return Intermed.class.getName();
}

public String getFinal() {
    return Final.class.getName();
}
```